# EMQX configuration to allow anonymous internal connection

Tags: mqtt, emq

I am using emqx as mqtt broker for my sensor network. Here is my desired configuration. 
I want to allow two different listeners for internal and external connections.

Listener 1
External: 0.0.0.0:8883
Do not allow anonymous connection
emqx_auth_http enabled
This listener is for sensors outside my VPC

Listener 2
Internal: 127.0.0.1:11883 
Allow anonymous connections 
This listener is intended for a few services that run on the same machine (localhost)

Here is my config file (relevant options)

```
##--------------------------------------------------------------------
## Authentication/Access Control
##--------------------------------------------------------------------

allow_anonymous = false

##--------------------------------------------------------------------
## Internal Zone
##--------------------------------------------------------------------

zone.internal.allow_anonymous = true


##--------------------------------------------------------------------
## Listeners
##--------------------------------------------------------------------

listener.tcp.external = 0.0.0.0:8883

listener.tcp.external.zone = external


##--------------------------------------------------------------------
## Internal TCP Listener for MQTT Protocol
##--------------------------------------------------------------------

listener.tcp.internal = 127.0.0.1:11883

listener.tcp.internal.zone = internal
```

Listener 1 is working perfectly fine with my custom authenticator API.

But the Listener 2 (internal listener) does not work as expected. It does not allow anonymous connections and fires the auth request to my API authenticator.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question based on the discussion on this issue https://github.com/emqx/emqx/issues/3225

The problem is that the HTTP auth plugin does not seem to honor the zone settings. In order to reach the internal zone auth configuration, we have to [ignore the HTTP auth as mentioned in the documentation.](https://docs.emqx.io/broker/latest/en/plugins.html#http-api-return-value-processing)

> #### Authentication succeeded HTTP
>
> Status Code: 200
>
> #### Ignore this certification HTTP
>
> Status Code: 200 Body: ignore
>
> #### Authentication failed HTTP
>
> Status Code: other than 200

Once that is sorted out, the following EMQX config works.

```
# Global 
allow_anonymous = false
# external
zone.external.allow_anonymous = false
listener.tcp.external = 0.0.0.0:1883
# internal
zone.internal.allow_anonymous = true
listener.tcp.internal = 127.0.0.1:11883
```

This setup ensures that the MQTT clients can:

- Connect anonymously at 11883 from localhost
- Connect on 1883 with HTTP auth from outside my VPC, and
- Not able to connect anonymously from outside my VPC

In my opinion, it would be better if setting up the internal zone to allow the anonymous connection itself bypasses the HTTP auth.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I create an issue on emqX github repository. Maybe you want to follow the resolution of that issue. https://github.com/emqx/emqx/issues/3225

It's not and answer but I'm struggling with the same problem. I hope that lead us to the solution.

Comment: "_it's not an answer_" - thus, please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details. While it might answer the question, just adding a github issue link does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Comment: I know but there isn't anything about that problem on stackoverflow or github with a solution. Only I'm directing people to the source of knowledge about emqx. On emqx docs says to get this setup running have to use zones but @Rahul is using it yet

Comment: Thanks @MoisésPérezEspinosa for raising the Issue. It is important to direct people to the issue.  
We can update the answer once the issue is resolved.